# Select from dropdown

Tags: typescript, testing, cypress

I'm trying to use Cypress to select an item from a dropdown list. This my test:

```
describe('Apollo', () => {
  it('Can open assembly', () => {
    cy.fixture('tmp.json').then((config) => {
      cy.visit(config.apollo_url)
      cy.contains('Continue as Guest').click()
      cy.reload()
      cy.contains('volvox_del')
    })
  })
})
```

I would like select, for example, the item `volvox_del`. But I get:

[image]

I also tried, among many other variations, to replace the line `cy.contains('volvox_del')` with:

```
cy.get('input[data-testid="assembly-selector"]').type('volvox_del')
```

which gives me:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Not enough detail to be exact, but it seems to me that `cy.reload()` needs something after it to make sure the page is in a steady state.

For example, use `cy.intercept()` to wait for the list to be populated. Or even/also bump up the timeout on your list item.

```js
cy.intercept(graphql-interceptor-here).as('data')

cy.contains('Continue as Guest').click()
cy.reload()

cy.wait('@data')
cy.contains('volvox_del', {timeout:10000})
```

You may be wondering why devtools are showing the text but Cypress never found it?

Be aware that the page is live and graphql requests will continue to update after the `contains()` has timed out.

The second approach is failing because the `<input>` is hidden (has attribute `aria-hidden="true"`) and is not meant to be used directly in that way - the user cannot type there, so really the test probably shouldn't do so either.

If that doesn't bother you and you want to just get passed the prompt, use `.type('volvox_del', {force:true})`.

Again, to make that work consistently you will need to ensure page has completely reloaded.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. However, I'm stuck with `graphql-interceptor-here`. Can you give any pointer of what it should look like? If it matters, the data comes from a mongodb database.